# Only allow a certain UIGestureRecognizer to perform at once

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to prevent UIGestureRecognizers working simultaneously, so I implemented the method below. However, I would only like to allow the otherGestureRecognizer to work on it's own while the gestureRecognizer is attempting to recognise simultaneously.

Please can you tell me how I can achieve that?

Btw, this is to prevent the view from panning (dragging) down while the tableView is in 'deletion mode'.

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear but I think you might be looking for:

```
- (void)requireGestureRecognizerToFail:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

From the [UIGestureRecognizer docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> This method creates a relationship with another gesture recognizer that delays the receiver’s transition out of UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible. The state that the receiver transitions to depends on what happens with otherGestureRecognizer: